# Installing and using JQuery in Brackets.io (mac)

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, adobe-brackets

I am working on a project that I want to use JQuery for since many people have recommended learning JQuery while learning Javascript and CSS to help enhance your programming abilities.

I looked into JQuery and downloaded both the compressed and uncompressed versions as well as the addition map files and notes, but I am semi-stuck on what to do next.

I understand that I must somehow import the script and implement it into my code, but I was reading online that Brackets.io may not support JQuery extensions or something about an issue with JSLint errors and files? I have no clue what any of this really means and I am just looking for a quick way to get JQuery plug-ins and code working in my current project.

I moved all the JQuery related files to my programming folder. What should I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML document head, insert the following tag:

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

replacing the jQuery version with the version you downloaded.

Then jQuery will be available from any script running from within that html document. You will need to include this line in the head of every document you plan to use jQuery with.

To add jQuery plugins, add additional script tags below the jQuery script tag, with each `src` pointing to the .js file of the plugin.

Comment: Does it matter where on my computer the files are? If it does, do I have to have a new jquery.js file for each seperate project (not page)?

Comment: For my answer as written, the jquery .js file needs to be in the same folder as your html page. And yes, I would recommend including exactly one copy of the jquery.js file in each of your projects. Paths in HTML are relative, so for example if you put your jquery .js file in a "scripts" folder that's in the same folder as your HTML page, you would be able to add it in the html by using `<script src="scripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>`